# State in react native

Tags: react-native

I am a beginner in react, but I have already searched in several places and I can't solve. My problem is change the value of variable in react native, basically I need create a function to set a variable with true or false, but when I try use the variable, it always is false.

In the constructor:

```
this.state = {
  uid: "",
  name: "",
  email: "",
  pass: "",
  loading: false
};
```

The function is call for the button:

```
setLoader = () => {
  console.log(this.state.loading);
  this.setState({ loading: !this.state.loading });
  console.log(this.state.loading);
};
```

The exit of console is:

```
[19:52:10] false
[19:52:10] false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because setting state is an asynchronous task. It takes time for it to set. If you try and call the value like you have done you will find that it hasn’t updated, this is expected behavior.

If you want to find out the value in state after you set it you should do the following

```
this.setState(previousState => { 
    return { loading: !previousState.loading }
}, () => console.log(this.state.loading));
```

setState takes a callback, which is called once the state has been set

Check out these three awesome articles that describe state

https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-is-asynchronous-52ead919a3f0

https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296

https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-function-56eb940f84b6

Comment: I understand, it worked, but I need to use the state of this variable to show a modal. When I call the function for the first time, the modal opens, when I call again nothing happens:
      <Loader loading={this.state.loading} color="#ff66be" />

Comment: You should check to make sure that the state is being set correctly using the callback method I gave, if it is being set correctly, then the problem is with the Loader.

Comment: Thank you, I will try fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is also another way to do this. You can use componentDidUpdate for listening for the state updates in one section and can make desired requests.

```
// The componentDidUpdate method will be called after each state update
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // Check if the count state has changed
    if (this.state.count !== prevState.count) {
      // Perform actions or fire events after state update here
      console.log('State has been updated. New count:', this.state.count);
    }
}
```